# Passing date to Date object results in an undefined variable in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I've been stuck on this for quite a while and would appreciate some help if possible.

Basically I receive a date from an API in the format yyyy-mm-dd. Amongst other things, I wish to display the weekday. Here is the relevant code:

```
// jsonDate is in the format yyyy-mm-dd 

var splitDate = jsonDate.split("-");
var joinedDate = splitDate.join(",");      

var myDate = new Date(joinedDate);

var weekday=new Array(7);
weekday[0]="Sun";
weekday[1]="Mon";
weekday[2]="Tue";
weekday[3]="Wed";
weekday[4]="Thu";
weekday[5]="Fri";
weekday[6]="Sat"; 

var dayOfTheWeek = weekday[myDate.getDay()];
```

Everything works as it should in Firefox, but in IE8 "dayOfTheWeek" is undefined. IE Developer tools also shows "myDate" as "NaN" when I console log it.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the date that way:

```
var myDate = new Date(splitDate[0],splitDate[1]-1,splitDate[2]);
```

Date expects the parts as single arguments, not as a formatted string.

There is also a option to pass a string, for example:

```
MonthAsString Day , year hours:minutes:seconds
```

but I think you better not use this, it might depend on the javascript-version, which format would be accepted.

Comment: Since the format is know, I too would have used `new Date(year,month-1,day)`. But the argument can be a string: ECMA-262, 15.9.3: `new Date ([string|number|[year[, month[, date[, hours[, minutes[, seconds[, ms]]]]]]]])`. If the value is a string it is parsed like `Date.parse(value)` and it accepts several different formats but standard allows for implementation-specific heuristics to determinate the format. FF, Chrome, Opera but not IE accepts `YYYY-MM-DD` (international). All of them accepts `M/D/YYYY`.

Comment: Additional note: None of them produces the same result on `.toString`: FF3.6: `WWW MMM DD YYYY hh:mm:ss GMT+hhmm`, Opera10: `WWW, MMM DD YYYY hh:mm:ss GMT+hhmm`, Chrome 6: `WWW MMM DD YYYY hh:mm:ss GMT+hhmm (text)`, IE8: `WWW MMM D hh:mm:ss UTC+hhmm YYYY`.

Comment: +1 Was wondering about this.  Thanks for clarifying @Dr.Molle!

Comment: @some: Additional info on the Date constructor. YYYY-MM-DD does not work in IE8 and below. It works as it should in newer browsers.

Comment: @EmilStenström  I certainly hope so, it's part of ECMAScript262-5. (bättre sent än aldrig)

Answer (score 0):

```
function dstring(str){
    //yyyy-mm-dd
    str= str.split(/\D+/);  
    str[1]-= 1;
    try{
        var d= new Date();
        d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
        d.setFullYear.apply(d, str);
    }
    catch(er){
        return 'Bad date-'+str;
    }
    return d;
}
```

**dstring('2010-10-21')**

```
/*  returned value: (Date)
Thu Oct 21 2010 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
*/
```